# Postgresql function load csv WITHOUT SUPERUSER

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, superuser

Does any way to load csv into postgresql table via COPY **WITHOUT SUPERUSER** privileges exist?

Comment: \copy is psql command as I know

Comment: but I need to do copy from function

Answer (score 6):

I managed to make it work like this:

```
cat myfile.csv | psql -d mydb -c "COPY landing_tbl(field01, field02...) FROM STDIN CSV;"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can either use

```
COPY tabname FROM 'filename'
```

which requires the superuser privilege or

```
COPY tabname FROM STDIN
```

which doesn't require the superuser privilege.

PostgreSQL requires the superuser privilege to access files on the database server for security reasons.

One workaround is to write a database function with `SECURITY DEFINER` owned by a superuser that does the `COPY` for you. Then everybody with `EXECUTE` rights on the function (by default everybody, so change that) can perform the operation.

Comment: Yes I know it. But how can I load from csv (via STDIN)?

Comment: You can only do that if the file is on the client side. For details I'd need to know what client or API you are using to access PostgreSQL.

Comment: I use RazorSQL to connect to remote DB

Comment: Using the [import tool](http://razorsql.com/features/postgresql_import.html) should do the trick.

Comment: That means that no any way to import csv data in function without superuser privileges?

Comment: That import tool probably uses `COPY FROM STDIN`. How do you want to use `COPY FROM STDIN` in a function? I guess I don't understand your problem. What do you want to achieve? Write a program? Do a one-time import into the database by hand?

Comment: Okay. I need to write a function which will load data from csv to multiple tables. And I also planned to call this function from simple sql script. No one-time import, because if I need only it, I will hadn't asked this question here.

Comment: I was confused because you mentioned RazorSQL. You cannot access data from a client machine inside a fumction. You cam use `COPY FROM STDIN` in an SQL script by including the literal data, but that's not what you want. I think you will have to write a program that does this load, an SQL script won't do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers!